# VBA run module 1, wait till finished then run module 2, wait till finished then run module 3, wait till finished then run module 4.?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Excel 2019
Windows

I have 4 page workbook and each page has a VBA module that performs various tasks on the data from the previous worksheet so they need to be run one after another but ONLY when the previous one has finished and at the moment they are being ran manually.

I would like to have a single module / macro, for arguements sake called "RunAll", that when clicked/envoked performs the same task.

Module1. Imports and cleans up data from a delimited txt file into sheet 1 - the data consistes of anywhere between 2000 - 110,000 lines.

Module2. Looks at Sheet 1 and selects certain data and formats it into Sheet 2.

Module3. Looks at Sheet 2 and selects certain data and formats it into Sheet 3.

Module4. Looks at Sheet 3 and selects certain data and formats it into Sheet 4.

Each module is coded in such a way that in knows which sheet to look at and where to insert its data.

This is a very simplified version so that you are not presented with a long post to read but when ran manually one after another they all work perfectly.

But if I simply try a maco that states:

```
Call module1
Call module2
Call module3
Call module4
```

The data on some sheets gets muddled up so and I suspect that as some modules take longer to run than others (module1 & module2), the other modules are being ran before all of the data is correctly imported and formatted before the precedeing ones have completed thier tasks.

So what I am trying to do is...

```
Call Module1 (and only when it has finished then)

Call Module2 (and only when it has finished then)

Call Module3  (and only when it has finished then)

Call Module4
```

I have performed copious searches online for possible answers before posting in here but nothing seems to match my needs and a good chunk of what I have found goes straight over my head?

Comment: You call *procedures*, not *modules*. `Module1.DoSomething` or `Call Module1.DoSomething`, or just `DoSomething`, assuming there's a `Public Sub DoSomething` in `Module1`.

Comment: "The data on some sheets gets muddled up" - sounds like your macros might have [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) that need to be qualified with an explicit `Worksheet` object. Rubberduck can help you find and fix them all.

Answer (score 1):

VBA is single threaded. So the different calls do  not execute simultaneously.

@Mathieu hits the nail on the head. If you call "module 1" macro manually with sheet1 selected but what happens when you execute manually with say sheet2 or 3 selected. You main need to hardcode the references to sheet#.

Comment: Yes each " procedure" is hard coded so it knows what work sheet it is acting upon.

Comment: There is maybe a small chance that the csv file refresh happens as an event or that you have added additional code onto any other events. You could first try inserting delays to see if this is part of your problem. If so you might want to disabled auto recalculate, screenrefresh and events then run your code in sequence then enable those again.